# Issues with executing user cron jobs in docker

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile

I am trying to create docker image that will execute cronjobs from root and custom made user. So far only root user is working:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2017.09
RUN yum -y install ca-certificates shadow-utils cronie && yum -y clean all
# root cronjob
RUN echo '* * * * * echo "$USER - Working in a coal mine..." > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2' > ~/cronjob
RUN chmod 0644 ~/cronjob
RUN crontab ~/cronjob
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ansible
# Ansible cronjob
USER ansible
RUN echo '* * * * * echo "$USER - Working in a coal mine..." > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2' > ~/cronjob
RUN chmod 0644 ~/cronjob
RUN crontab ~/cronjob
USER root
CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond", "-n"]
```

I build this docker using this command `docker build -t demotest -f Dockerfile .`
I execute the created image using this command `docker run -t -i demotest:latest`

Result of execution:

```
> docker run -t -i demotest:latest
root - Working in a coal mine...
root - Working in a coal mine...
root - Working in a coal mine...
root - Working in a coal mine...
```

Few details:

```
docker run -t -i demotest:latest bash -c 'ls -l /home/ansible/cronjob'
-rw-r--r-- 1 ansible ansible 81 Jul 11 16:06 /home/ansible/cronjob

docker run -t -i demotest:latest bash -c 'ls -l /root/cronjob'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 81 Jul 11 16:06 /root/cronjob

docker run -t -i demotest:latest bash -c 'crontab -u root -l'
* * * * * echo "$USER - Working in a coal mine..." > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2

docker run -t -i demotest:latest bash -c 'crontab -u ansible -l'
* * * * * echo "$USER - Working in a coal mine..." > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Updated information

I changed `CMD` to look like this: `CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond", "-n", "-x", "sch"]`

This generated the output:

```
docker run -t -i demotest:latest
debug flags enabled: sch
[1] cron started
log_it: (CRON 1) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 85% if used.)
log_it: (CRON 1) INFO (running with inotify support)
[1] GMToff=0
[1] Target time=1562865060, sec-to-wait=12
user [root:0:0:...] cmd="run-parts /etc/cron.hourly"
user [root:0:0:...] cmd="[ ! -f /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && run-parts /etc/cron.monthly"
user [root:0:0:...] cmd="[ ! -f /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && run-parts /etc/cron.weekly"
user [root:0:0:...] cmd="[ ! -f /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ] && run-parts /etc/cron.daily"
user [ansible:500:500:...] cmd="echo "$USER - Working in a coal mine..." > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2"
user [root:0:0:...] cmd="echo "$USER - Working in a coal mine..." > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2"
Minute-ly job. Recording time 1562865061
[1] Target time=1562865120, sec-to-wait=60
Minute-ly job. Recording time 1562865061
log_it: (root 8) CMD (echo "$USER - Working in a coal mine..." > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2)
log_it: (ansible 9) CMD (echo "$USER - Working in a coal mine..." > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2)
root - Working in a coal mine...
```

This shows that the custom user cronjob is executed but output is not redirected.
So the questions changes to - How to properly redirect stdout to host console?

Comment: Hypothesis: since the cron daemon is running as root, `/proc/1/fd/1` is owned by root, and the non-root cron job can’t write there.

Comment: Most likely you are correct there. What would you suggest as a workaround if there is any?

Answer (score -2):

Change last line of your Dockerfile:

from

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond", "-n", "-x", "sch"]
```

to

```
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Note:
cron -f --> cron foreground

Comment: This is incorrect. Amazon linux uses cronie crond which does not have parameter -f.